# In Street View, what is the distance between consecutive panoramic photographs?

Tags: google-maps

I'm curious in Google Maps Street View, what distance is it between two consecutive panoramic photos?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no global distance, but you can measure it yourself. Here are some tutorials:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/1628031?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

http://www.theverge.com/2014/7/9/5885065/distance-measurement-tool-added-to-google-maps

Comment: I have no proof but I had a hunch they may vary based on speed of the vehicle, accuracy of GPS position, lane position, hardware revisions, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks, I can do a rough measurement with this method. It is quite possible as Mimp said that there is no exact distance, but it depends on a lot of things. So it's not like every 10 meters a picture is taken ?